Does there exist an example where manipulating both sides of a Trigonometric equation to prove an identity give a false positive?
Now I know to prove Trigonometric identities we can:

prove that LHS is equal to the RHS

prove that RHS is equal to the LHS

Prove that RHS = X and LHS  = X, thus RHS = LHS


Now there many examples say that you can't manipulate both sides by cross-multiplying, squaring both sides and etc..
Example1 suppose we wanted to "prove" that $-3 = 3$, if we square both sides then we get: $9 = 9$ and we get a false positive.
Example2 let $A\neq B$ and we "prove" that $A = B$. If we multiply both sides by $0$ we get: $0=0$ and agian a false positive.
Example3 let $g(x) = \{0 \ \textrm{for} \  x\neq 0 \ \textrm{and} \ 4 \ \textrm{if} \ x = 0\}$ and $h(x) = \{0 \ \textrm{for} \  x\neq 0 \ \textrm{and} \ 3 \ \textrm{if} \ x = 0\}$. If we "prove" that $g(x) = h(x)$ by multipling both sides by $\sin(x)$ we get:  $\sin(x)g(x) = \sin(x)h(x)\implies 0=0$ thus another false positive
Example4 (extra solutions) $x = 1$, multiply both sides by $x$ we get: $x^2 = x$ where $x = 0$ or $x = 1$ where clearly we have to discard $x = 0$ as $x = 1\neq 0$.
Thus these are some of the cases that point out why we can't just manipulate the equation, But my question is:
Suppose that we only have an equation with trig functions and constants(does not contain any other functions like polynomials, g(x) like above, etc...), and also we only multiply by trig functions(not their inverses) and using already known identities(not squaring, using inverse trig funcitons or multiplying by zero etc...) is there an example where it shows us arriving at a false positive when trying to prove trig identities?
So to claify, Only using the $\times,\div,+,-$ of non-inverse trig funcitons and using the $\times,\div,+,-$   constants not including the multiplication\division of $0$

It depends on the domain. For example $\arcsin(\sin(4\pi))\neq 4\pi$

@RedFive, thank you for your answer, but suppose we don't use inverse trig functions? I will update the question.

Yes, I did think that may have been what you were asking. It seemed too obvious, hence I didn't write it as an answer.

If I understand you correctly, this can be viewed as being in the field $\mathbb{C}(e^{ix})$ so multiplication by anything nonzero is invertible, so is always a valid proof step.

You say what operations you're not interested in (squaring, inverse trig functions) but which operations do you want to know if they're valid?

@ZoeAllen, basically just the multiplying/dividing and +- of non-inverse trig funcitons. and same for constants not including the multiplication\division of 0

Then my comment answers your question. But you'd need to be comfortable with what fields are for an explanation along those lines to work.

@ZoeAllen I would like the explanation , and if it contains stuff that I am not familiar with I can always look it up and try to understand it. I just need to be "pointed in the right direction".

it's occurred to me that it doesn't actually answer the question for identities like $\sin((1+\sqrt{2})x)=\cos(\sqrt{2}x)\sin(x)+\sin(\sqrt{2}x)\cos(x)$. For that you'd need a bigger field, like the meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$.

A field is basically defined as something where you can add, subtract, multiply, or divide both sides of an equation without turning a false identity into a true one (as long as you don't multiply or divide by $0$). So your question is the same as asking if the collection of functions you describe forms a field.
A field would more usually be defined as something that satisfies the field axioms. For example, all these things are true of the real numbers with addition and multiplication, so $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ is a field. You can check yourself that the complex numbers, $(\mathbb{C},+,\cdot)$, satisfy these axioms for another example. Other examples of fields are the rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, (link), and the integers mod $p$ (link). We can add, subtract, multiply and divide (except by $0$) elements of a field however we like and we'll always get another element of the field.
We can use the complex definitions of
$$\sin z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
$$\cos z = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$
and
$$\tan z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})}$$
to find a field that contains everything you can make from trig functions (under some restrictions) and, because they're contained in a field, we will then know we can add, subtract, multiply and divide them by each other (except $0$) without making false identities.
Firstly, we need to see why fields are structures where you can't turn false equations into true ones: The 'additive inverse' condition is just saying we can subtract numbers by each other, and the multiplicative inverse condition is just saying we can divide numbers by each other (except we can't divide by $0$). To get $\frac{a}{b}$, we take the multiplicative inverse of $b$, which the axioms tell us exists (if $b \neq 0$) and $a \cdot b^{-1}$ is what we call $\frac{a}{b}$. Same with subtraction. We know from the axioms that dividing by $b$ cancels out multiplying by $b$, because $a \cdot b^{-1} \cdot b = a \cdot 1 = a$ using the axioms of multiplicative inverse and identity. We can do the same for subtraction.
We know that doing the same thing to both sides of a true equation always produces another true equation, but sometimes we can get a true equation where we started with a false one, like your $3 = -3$ example shows. But if an operation is invertible, we know it will work both ways. For example, adding $4$ is invertible because its inverse operation is subtracting $4$ (this always gets you back to what you started with). If $a = b$, we know $a + 4 = b + 4$, but because of the inverse operation, we also know that if $a + 4 = b + 4$, $a = b$, by subtracting $4$ from each side. $a+4=b+4$ implies $a=b$, so adding $4$ to both sides can't ever get us from a false equation to a true one.
Your $3 = -3$ example breaks because squaring doesn't have an inverse: for the positive numbers, the square root is an inverse, but for the negative numbers it isn't because squaring $-3$ gives you $9$, but square rooting $9$ gives you $3$, which wasn't what you started with. Any operations that map two numbers to the same place can't be invertible because when you try to invert it, you'll end up putting one of them back where the other one started. Similarly, multiplying by $0$ isn't invertible.
The field axioms tell us that addition and multiplication are invertible. The operation $+x$ is undone by the operation $-x$, for any element $x$ in the field. Similarly, subtraction is invertible because the operation $-x$ is undone by the operation $+x$, and division by a nonzero $x$ is invertible because the operation $/x$ is undone by the operation $\cdot x$. Just like before, this invertibility tells us that the operations $+x$, $-x$, $\cdot x$ and $/x$ won't get us from a false equation to a true one.
To find a field that contains the trig functions we're interested in, we'll start by noting that $\mathbb{C}(X)$, the collection rational functions with complex coefficients, is a field because $\mathbb{C}$ is a field and the rational functions over any field are always another field (if anyone has a link to a proof of this please share).
Then we want to make a new field, which behaves in exactly the same way, by replacing all the 'X' with '$e^{iz}$' to make $\mathbb{C}(e^{iz})$. This will still be a field because all the identities that held before will still hold after we do this replacement. E.g.
$$\frac{1}{X+1} + \frac{X+2}{2X} = \frac{X^2+5X+2}{2X^2+2X}$$
so
$$\frac{1}{e^{iz}+1} + \frac{e^{iz}+2}{2e^{iz}} = \frac{(e^{iz})^2+5e^{iz}+2}{2(e^{iz})^2+2e^{iz}}$$
Because all the algebra is the same, if $+$, $-$, $/$ and $\cdot$ were invertible before, they're still invertible.
But now the elements of our field are functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, so we have a collection of functions where, if we have an equation involving them, we can add, subtract, multiply, and divide (except by $0$) without turning true equations into false ones. And using the definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$, we know that these functions are part of our collection, $\mathbb{C}(e^{iz})$. And so everything that we can build out of them by adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing is also in $\mathbb{C}(e^{iz})$.
So if we have an equation where both sides of the equation are trig functions in $\mathbb{C}(e^{iz})$, and we add, subtract, multiply, or divide both sides of the equation by a trig function in $\mathbb{C}(e^{iz})$ (except 0) then the new equation will be true only if the one we started with was.
This proves we won't turn a false equation into a true one for trig functions on the complex numbers, and you're (presumably) interested in the real numbers. But if an identity holds for the complex numbers it has to hold for the real numbers because the real numbers are included in the complex numbers.
Notes on what is contained in $\mathbb{C}(e^{iz})$: $\mathbb{C}(e^{iz})$ contains, among other things, anything we can make by adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing $\sin$ and $\cos$, but there are some things it doesn't contain, like $\sin \frac{x}{2}$, $\sin(\sqrt{2}x)$, and $\sin(\cos(x))$. For identities involving this broader class of trig identities, the sketch proof I have provided isn't good enough. We'd need a bigger field which contains all of these.
There is such a field, the field of meromorphic functions, so by proving that the meromorphic functions are a field and that these are indeed meromorphic, you would prove it for this broader class of trig functions as well.
I've tried to cover a lot of ground here so if it seems like I've skipped a step please tell me.

Thank you for your answer, I have a question: why did you have to make a new field with $e^{iz}$? If  $\mathbb{C}(X)$ is collection rational functions with complex coefficients, then shouldn't $e^{iz}$ already be included in $X \in \mathbb{C}$?

@Reuben I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're asking. $e^{iz}$ is an element in a field and $X$ is an element in a field, and $X$ is (for our purposes) a function, so it is not contained in $\mathbb{C}$.
